# Finding the required number of graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

A simple undirected graph has no self-loops and no parallel edges.

Determine how many of the simple undirected graphs $G$ = $(V,E)$ with $V$ = ${1,...,5}$ contain a vertex $v$ of degree $deg(v)$ = $4$

How to find the required number of graphs with V =5.

I could only find the total number of graphs. Couldn't proceed.

Comment: I think there are few enough graphs with 5 vertices that one can just draw them all and count the ones that have 4-degree vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the graph with the fewest number of edges: Just a star. A vertex connected to all other ones. 
Then without breaking the structure we can construct all possible graphs on the other 4 vertices, and there are gonna be exactly $2^{C^{4}_{2}}$ of these. Therefore there will be $2^{C^{4}_{2}}=2^6=64$ graphs.

Comment: Well, this assumes we mean unlabeled graphs...